# Atpana 3 - How can I switch the current remote for a project?

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Atpana 3 for a project which has both a development and live server, I'd like to be able to have both set up as a Remote, then be able to switch which one to use for the project. They're both set up as a remote in the remotes view, but when I go to `Project -> Properties -> File Transfer` The `connection` dropdown only contains the remote that I initially set the project up with - How do I add the other one to this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set up the project with the first server, you could right-click on the project and select **Publish** (or **Deploy**) -> **Connections** -> **Add New Connection...** Then in the connection manager dialog, select the second server as the destination and click OK. Now the project would be set up to connect to both servers.

Afterward, if you go to Project -> Properties -> File Transfer, you should see both servers listed in the combo box, and if **Use the connection as default** is unchecked, there will be a popup asking which server to use each time an upload or synchronization is performed; checking it makes the operation to always use the selected server.

Hope this helps.